# Хеширование SHA-256 на видеокарте. Решение, которое использовало бы GPU

Tags: c++, python, c, хеширование, sha256

Нужно увеличить скорость хеширования sha256 через python. Стандартный hashlib работает через CPU. Какую библиотеку и/или решение использовать для GPU хеширования. Готовых решений нигде не нашёл...

UPD:
Не обязательно python. Нужно простое решение которое бы использовало GPU.

Comment: Почему GPU вдруг должно быть быстрее? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530852/cpu-hashes-faster-than-gpu

Comment: @user366004, так уж получилось, что солнце больше чем луна, а gpu считает sha256 быстрее чем cpu

Comment: @PavelGridin Раз уж заговорили аналогиями, то добраться до солнца гораздо сложней чем до луны, а информация добирается до и от GPU горааздо длинным путем. И операции на GPU профитны далеко не везде.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, ну я исходил из предположения, что человеку нужен массовый расчёт

Comment: в общем думаю надо начать с поиска по двум словам opencl и sha256

Comment: Я перелопатил все библиотеки на питоне и которые компилируется nvcc ничего не работает..

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/speed-hashing/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047601/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gpu-to-accelerate-hashing-in-python

Comment: @ГеннадийП, интересно, а какая зависимость длины провода мыши от скорости реакции курсора? и может расскажете, что майнинг фермы лучше делать на CPU?

Comment: @alex В первом комментарии по ссылке почитайте почему GPU имеет довольно большой (относительно) лаг. Майнинг - это одна и та же задача с практически одними и теми же данными, что идеально подходит для расчетов на GPU. А вот например хеширование какого нть потока данных - тут уже GPU начинает проигрывать.

Answer (score 6):

Судя по комментариям, автору интересен расчёт хеша для отдельных значений.

Начать с того что алгоритм расчёта одного хеша [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) не подразумевает параллелизацию: каждое промежуточное значение [является функцией от предыдущего](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68779/42956), и так далее до исходного. То есть, нет никакого смысла и не будет никакой выгоды от расчёта одного хеша на GPU.

Использование GPU для таких операций не приведёт к какому-либо выигрышу, и даже сделает всю операцию существенно медленней. GPU рассчитан на параллельную обработку больших массивов информации, что подразумевает под собой [существенные временные расходы](https://community.khronos.org/t/why-is-gpu-cpu-transfer-slow/58708/7) на буферизацию, сброс состояния, и так далее.

Если вы обрабатываете огромные массивы информации, например, как при 3D рендеринге или обучении нейронных сетей, то эти задержки не делают погоды. Но вы их всё равно учитываете, например, при подборе размера батча для алгоритмов машинного обучения - он [не должен быть слишком маленьким](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/GPU-Memory-Size-and-Deep-Learning-Performance-batch-size-12GB-vs-32GB----1080Ti-vs-Titan-V-vs-GV100-1146/).

Если же вы собираетесь обрабатывать буквально байты, то - мои сожаления - GPU вам не поможет. Затраты времени на передачу информации туда-сюда с CPU на GPU и обратно превысят любое возможное ускорение от параллелизации расчёта. Которой, как мы уже выяснили, не может быть при расчёте отдельных значений.

Наверное потому автор не нашел готовых библиотек для этой операции.